# Creating a loop that continuously puts out output until user types a word to stop the process

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a code in java that continuously spits out what the x variable is every 10 milliseconds until the user inputs the String that breaks the loop. I was wondering how to code it.. I have the following right now. The code is currently running and just stopping where the Scanner is suppose to scan for the next line instead of continuously printing out what variable x is.

```
public static void show() {
    while (true) {
        if (showWatch.elapsedTime1() > 10) {
            System.out.println(x);
            showWatch.start();
            x = x + 1;
            wait(1000);
        }
        else if (showWatch.elapsedTime1() < 10) {
            while (showWatch.elapsedTime1() < 10) {
                response = scan.nextLine();
            }
            if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP")) {
                break;
            }
            else if (showWatch.elapsedTime1() > 10) {
                System.out.println(x);
                showWatch.start();
                x = x + 1;
                wait(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do you code a loop that will only continuously print the variable's content until the user types in a word to stop the program?

Comment: What is wrong with the code that you currently have? Do you get an error? Not doing what you want?

Comment: The program is stopping on the scan line and not continuously printing out what the variable x is every 10 milliseconds.

Comment: If the program is stopped waiting, then other actions you may want to perform will have to be performed on another thread, one which isn't stopped waiting. Note that the console is ill-designed for this use case as it is likely to write the value of x while the user is typing STOP. Consider having a GUI or not doing this.

Comment: What is `showWatch` and why does it matter?  You're going to want to include that as context into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scanner will not work if something is printed during typing. But if the interval is big enough it could work. I use the Semaphore so that the Printer-Thread sleeps as long he has no ticket.

```
public class Printer extends Thread {

    public Semaphore stopped = new Semaphore(1);
    private int x;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                stopped.acquire();
                System.out.println(++x);
                stopped.release();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Printer printer = new Printer();
        printer.start();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) {
            String command = scan.nextLine();
            if ("BREAK".equals(command)) {
                printer.stopped.acquire(1);
            } else if ("RESTART".equals(command)) {
                printer.stopped.release(1);
            }
        }
}
```